# Is there a way to define named ranges through Google Docs GUI?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, named-ranges

I know that Named Ranges are a feature of Google Docs, but I can't seem to find any way to define/assign them using the GUI. Is this possible or can it only be done programmatically via Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the Docs editor does not support that option natively, only from the API.
There is nothing I could find regarding this, only the Docs API [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/NamedRange)

Comment: same here. i think it's fairly similar to MS Word in that respect, where you cannot give names to page elements (ex. text boxes, images, shapes, etc) through the UI -- it can only be done with VB

Answer (score 1):

In Google' GUI cannot do this. But there is a third party library - https://github.com/tanaikech/DocNamedRangeApp

This repository has an example where working with ranges implemented in the sidebar - https://github.com/tanaikech/DocNamedRangeApp/tree/master/samples

Instructions for its - https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/36a2a9d393f42274a833e5660bfe4ce0

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73470054