# How can I add years of experience to my CV/resumé so that it goes up by 1 every year by itself?

Tags: google-docs

I have a document (a CV) in a Google document. I list years of experience for my core skills. They have been going up every year. I'd like to automate the process so that, every year, the number automatically goes up by 1.

If I were coding I'd just work out "print number of years (rounded up) since the date I started working on this skill".

How can I do this in a Google Doc?

e.g. "15 years in the industry" should become "16 years in the industry" after I cross the midpoint of my 16th year.

NOTE: this question is for a Google Doc, NOT spreadsheet.

Comment: Use a function like today() or now() - both are in Excel, but there will be equivalent ones.

Comment: A combination of [DATEDIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612) and [TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984) seems like it would achieve the desired result.

Comment: From your question and tag, if you want to achieve your goal with a Google Document, how about the following flow? 1. Set a named range to the position of text you want to update. 2. Using the OnOpen trigger, when the Google Document is opened, the text of the named range is updated by Google Apps Script. I think that by this flow, your goal can be achieved. But, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question. So, I proposed this as a comment. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: By the way, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73467787 But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike You understood it correctly, it's for a Google document.

Comment: @Asfand Qazi Thank you for replying. When you are using Google Documents, is my suggestion in my previous comment useful?